# Django Elastic Beanstalk deploy issue: wsgi.py cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, wsgi

I´m trying to deploy a Django app in Elastic Beanstalk from AWS.

I am able to deploy it but get a `500 Internal Server Error`.

In the log I see:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=3640):
    Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/locallibrary/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=3640):
    Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/locallibrary/wsgi.py'.
```

---

Following the instructions from:
http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html

I download the latest WSGI code from: 
https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases

Go to downloads folder, unzip the file, get into the directory.

When I run ./configure I get the following response:

```
checking for apxs2... no
checking for apxs... /usr/sbin/apxs
apxs:Error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config not found!.
apxs:Error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config not found!.
cat: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool: No such file or directory
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/admin/downloads/mod_wsgi-4.6.4':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

The config.log is:

```
checking for apxs2... no
checking for apxs... /usr/sbin/apxs
apxs:Error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config not found!.
apxs:Error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config not found!.
cat: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool: No such file or directory
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/admin/downloads/mod_wsgi-4.6.4':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
(djangodev) Mac-Pro-de-admin-4:mod_wsgi-4.6.4 admin$ ls
CREDITS.rst Makefile    apxs        configure   images      src     win32
LICENSE     Makefile.in config.log  configure.ac    libtool     tests
MANIFEST.in README.rst  config.status   docs        setup.py    tox.ini
(djangodev) Mac-Pro-de-admin-4:mod_wsgi-4.6.4 admin$ nano config.log

  GNU nano 2.0.6                                  File: config.log                                                                            

PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PYTHON=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host_alias=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: And what is the Python stack trace and exception details that follow that in the error log.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jun 22 15:27:16.890000 2018] [:error] [pid 3308] [remote 172.31.35.41:204]   File "/opt/python/current/app/locallibrary/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
[Fri Jun 22 15:27:16.890027 2018] [:error] [pid 3308] [remote 172.31.35.41:204]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Fri Jun 22 15:27:16.890045 2018] [:error] [pid 3308] [remote 172.31.35.41:204] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi

Comment: Is Django installed? Have you configured mod_wsgi to tell it to use any virtual environment that Django was installed into? Is mod_wsgi compiled for the same version of Python you want to use? You cannot point mod_wsgi compiled for one Python version to use a virtual environment for a different Python version. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: Hi. I have django installed and the application runs ok locally. ButI I realized there is a problem with my wsgi install. In this document I you have the info and the log: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Q2hGmeHQratyhoB3VE0VguPUJFSCjsMqYFFlxItW8So/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please include the information here, not off somewhere else.

Comment: Ok. Just added it to the original question. Thank you very much.

Comment: If deploying to Elastic Beanstalk, why are you trying to build mod_wsgi on macOS?

Comment: Where should I install it?

Comment: You should perhaps look at AWS documentation on how to use Python in Elastic Beanstalk. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-container.html